# How to take Parameter Variance: Experiment parameter Min, Max and Step value from Parameter Variance Screen Text Box

Tags: anylogic

I am working on **Parameter Variance: Experiment** in one model. Assume there is one parameter **Rate** on which I need to run experiment. For that I need to insert Min, Max, Step value in Parameter Variance properties page.
I want to take these Min, Max, Step parameter values as an input in the text box from the user in the **Model main page ( Experiment page)**. Now please suggest how to take these values from **model main page** and assign to main variables in **Parameter Variance** before running the experiment

Comment: AFAIK, there is no easy way to do this. You'd have to go through a Custom Experiment. I haven't tried doing it with a Parameter Variation Experiment myself, but there are templates available in the Example models if you search for "Custom Experiment",

Comment: @Shingston, I saw those models, But I couldn't get the right answer, If you know specific model, which can work for this issue, let me know,  I will study that model again.                                                                                                                                 I am waiting for more reply to resolve this issue.                                          
#AnyLogic, #Simulation, #Java